# Persistence of entity in more than one step (ASP.NET MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, orm, entity-framework-5

My friends, i've come trhough a situation i haven't come before. I have one entity (aka Person ;) that i need to save. But the thing is that i have groups of information of a person that i wish to ask for the user to input in more than one controller, this way the user won't have to fill a extense form. He'll go in steps filling the forms for Personal Info, Academic Info, Job History Info, etc. I'm using MVC 4. Do I have to create one controller to each form/view? Because my entity has all atributes i need to persist at once (by the way i plan to use an ORM, haven't decides if it will be NHibernate or Entity Framework yet). Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create a new controller for each view. That's actually not what you want to do.  Sounds like you may be coming from WebForms, which would require a different page for each form.

MVC doesn't work like this. Just simply create a new action and view for each page.

As far as persisting data, there are numerous ways to do this. You can use session data, or more preferably, a database(model) to store the data. You can use something like ADO.NET/Entity Framework to help with this so you don't have to mess with the dirty database details.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it useful to instanciate this person entity and preserve the partially filled data in the `ViewBag` or any other (global variable) that you prefer to use.
this way, what ever design you follow, either single controller, if possible, or multiple. you would just need to get the data from viewbag and persist it into DB.

It will also allow you to navigate in forms easily and data could be populated by using the viewbag.

Comment: I've thought about view bag either... i was confused just by the concept of responsability of controllers and actions... now it1s all clear.. thanks for the quick answer =)

Comment: My pleasure sir. yes, you can have that scenario.